# Hungerfords definition of the discriminant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, discriminant

Hungerfords Algebra Definition 4.4:

Let $K$ be a field with char$K \neq 2$ and $f \in K[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with $n$ distinct roots $u_1,..u_n$ in some splitting field $F$ of $f$ over $K$. Let $\Delta=\prod_{i<j}(u_i-u_j)$; the discriminant of $f$ is $D=\Delta^2$.

I learned that the definition of a quadratic $g(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is $D=b^2-4ac$. Hungerfords definition of a discrimant does not lead to this discrimiant. The roots of $g(x)$ are $u_i=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$.

However:

$(u_1-u_2)^2 = \frac{b^2-4ac}{a^2}$.

Is this just an unfortunate inconsistency in mathematical terminology? Discriminant's are something that I've wanted to know more about for some time now so that would be a little disappointing to me

Comment: The first definition of $\Delta$ is common. When first learning the quadratic formula we call $b^2-4ac$ the discriminant because we really just care about whether this is $>0,=0,$ or $<0$. The cases of $>0,=0,$ or $<0$ are exactly the same as with the other discriminant: $\frac{b^2-4ac}{a^2}$. Also note that, if we take $f$ to be monic, then both discriminants agree.

Comment: Some authors add a factor $a_n^{2n-2}$ which would get you $b^2-4ac$.

Comment: The roots define a polynomial (only) up to a constant factor. The given definition of the discriminant depends solely on the roots, so two polynomials which differ only by a multiplicative factor will have the same discriminant according to this definition. Indeed, your $D=\Delta$ for monic quadratics.